# Displaying 3 dimensional arrays in correct order PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

So I have dynamically created form with Jquery and after sending this form. I want to retrive it in correct order which I got myself confused in doing.

The problem is when you add multiple spells to a champion let's say 3 and delete middle one it will description and 'change' won't show up here is the code responsible for retriving variables from those arrays:

```
foreach($_POST['champion'] as $champion){
                if(empty($_POST['GeneralChangeDescription'][$ChampionNumber])){
                $NumberOfStats[$ChampionNumber+1] =0;}
                if(!empty($_POST['GeneralChangeDescription'][$ChampionNumber])){
                    foreach($_POST['GeneralChangeDescription'][$ChampionNumber] as $indexGeneral=>$GeneralChangeDescription){
                    $GeneralChangeDescriptions[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexGeneral+1] = $GeneralChangeDescription;
                    $GeneralChange[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexGeneral+1]=$_POST['GeneralChange'][$ChampionNumber][$indexGeneral];

                    $NumberOfStats[$ChampionNumber+1] = count($_POST['GeneralChangeDescription'][$ChampionNumber]);                 
                    }
                }
                if(!empty($_POST['change'][$ChampionNumber])){
                    foreach($_POST['change'][$ChampionNumber] as $indexSpell=>$change){
                        $SpellIcon[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexSpell+1] = $change;
                        $SpellTitle[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexSpell+1] = $_POST['championSpell'][$ChampionNumber][$indexSpell];
                        $NumberOfSpellsChampion[$ChampionNumber+1] =count($_POST['change'][$ChampionNumber]);
                        foreach($_POST['SpellDescription'][$ChampionNumber][$indexSpell] as $indexChange=>$SpellDescription){
                            echo $ChampionNumber;
                            $ChampionNumberSpellNumber[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexSpell+1] =count($_POST['SpellDescription'][$ChampionNumber][$indexSpell]);
                            $SpellChange[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexSpell+1][$indexChange+1]=$_POST['SpellChange'][$ChampionNumber][$indexSpell][$indexChange];
                            $SpellDescriptions[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexSpell+1][$indexChange+1]=$SpellDescription;
                        }
                    }   
                }
                $ChampionNumber++;
                $championArray[$ChampionNumber] = $champion;
            }
```

Here is JSfiddle with dynamic form http://jsfiddle.net/e2fk9793/

Here is an explanation how those arrays work https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdLOo.jpg

The third foreach array is the one that is not working (Notice: Undefined offset: 2)

Comment: check if that index exists then ...before you try to use it. You are probably overshooting the length of the array when you increment index

Comment: anyway to do that? another loop that would go through array and checked every field if it exists?

Comment: use a simple `if ( isset($variable) )`

Comment: that did not work unfortunately

Comment: make a recursive function calling itself each time it runs into an array...?